# apt-get update high cpu http process

Tags: apt, updates, python3

I also asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203821/apt-get-update-keeps-downloading).

When I do `apt-get update`, it keeps on updating. I stopped the process at 22 Gb - I just canceled it... Any idea about what to do?

ot sure if related, but HTTP process is running 2x and getting at 70% cpu per process... System gets all sluggish. Using cpulimit I can limit it to only 10% or so. Removed webmin because i thought the python from that was the cause.. not sure now.

```
Get:42 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages [134 kB]                            
Get:43 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main i386 Packages [1361 kB]                                  
Get:44 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted i386 Packages [15,5 kB]                            
Get:45 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe i386 Packages [6486 kB]                              
Get:46 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse i386 Packages [134 kB]                             
Get:47 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en [793 kB]                                  
Get:48 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en [103 kB]                            
Get:49 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en [4228 B]                            
Get:50 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en [4456 kB]                             
Get:51 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources [52,7 kB]                                
Get:52 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources [28 B]                             
Get:53 hxxp://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources [356 B]                              
Ign hxxp://download.virtualbox.org vivid/contrib Translation-en_US                                      
Ign hxxp://download.virtualbox.org vivid/contrib Translation-en                              
Ign hxxp://download.virtualbox.org vivid/non-free Translation-en_US                          
Ign hxxp://download.virtualbox.org vivid/non-free Translation-en                             
100% [53 Sources 6133 MB/6133 MB 100%] [41 Packages 7834 MB/7834 MB 100%]
```

I noticed that when running apt-get update, the process start 2x an python3 http process? Which is really CPU consuming ~70% per process.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could delete the soures.list file, and then push setting and then the update icon, and then hatch the upper chranoical, and then reload and it might work fine this way

Comment: How do you mean push setting? Did you mean moving sources.list to sources.list.old and then do an apt-get update?

Comment: I did what i just said: move sources.list to sources.list.od and then did an apt-get update. Spotify source gave some errors about the key, so i re-added that key. Looks like the problem is solved. Will mark as answer comming monday if situation doesnt change.